# Paypay website payments standard API: pay without paypal account

Tags: paypal

we have set up Paypal as a hook into an e-commerce application, where users just enter their paypal account, and we link their clients through to their Paypal account when buying products.

This works great, and paypal asks you to login to pay for your purchases.
But we don't want clients to be forced to create a paypal account, just to make a purchase.

Does website payments standard API actually support paying without a paypal account?
At the moment this is a real showstopper for us.

Answer (score 1):

Check out PayPal Adaptive Accounts.  You can create PP accounts for your users.  The only step they'll have to complete at PayPal is creating a password.  Once the account is created you might need send the user back through a checkout flow.

[Adaptive Accounts](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/adaptive-accounts)

Use the Adaptive Accounts API to build applications that create and manage PayPal accounts. Merchants and developers can use the API to create PayPal accounts, add payment methods to accounts, and verify a PayPal account status.

Answer (score 0):

Paypal is a very useful payment service gateway, exactly because the customer does not need to enter a credit-card number.

What we do, is offer Paypal as an option. We allow credit-card entry as well. In order to evaluate the credit-card for validity etc., we interface with the bank that supports our account and let their system do the checks. Another option would be "Cash on Delivery".

Comment: yep, cash on delivery is an option. But I do know that paypal offers VISA as a payment option without the need for a paypal account. I just don't know if it's in the personal account / website payments standard and I'm looking for some help in that direction.

Comment: Why don't you e-mail them? It would be interesting to post the response here.